# Index of maximal subgroups of subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group such that every maximal subgroup is of finite index, and let $H\leq G$ be a finitely generated subgroup of $G$. Then, must every maximal subgroup of $H$ be of finite index?

Comment: A very closely related property "Property MF" is in my 2006 Geom. Dedic. paper [Finitely presented wreath products and double coset decompositions](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509090), Def. 3.9: it means that every subgroup contained in finitely many subgroups has finite index. Your question is equivalent whether Property MF passes to finitely generated subgroups. I'm not sure the answer is known, because the class of groups known to have Property MF is extremely restricted (it's known to include Grigorchuk's first group, nilpotent-by-polycyclic f.g. groups). So I think your question is open.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer. Is it known in the case where H is of finite index in G?

Comment: PS I was too hasty saying "your question is equivalent...", although it's of a similar spirit (saying "Property MF for f.g. group passes to f.g. subgroups"). For your question, I don't know if it's known, I guess it's not.

Comment: Well, I tend to believe that there are counterexamples. Idea: find a metabelian f.g. group $H$, a prime $p$ and an infinite $\mathbf{F}_pH$-module $V$ with exactly $3$ submodules, namely $\{0\}$, $V$, and some finite index subgroup $W$ of $V$. Then $G\ltimes V$ would have all its maximal subgroups of finite index, but not its finite index subgroup $G\ltimes W$. For suitable $H$ lamplighter there exists infinite irreducible $\mathbf{F}_pH$-modules for suitable $p$ (Ph. Hall), so the existence of $V$ sounds plausible to me.

Comment: This is true for linear groups: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=613853

Comment: This is also true for the Grigorchuk group: see Theorem 1 & and the last statement of this math review: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2009443